# php does not work on some servers

Tags: php, authentication

I found a set of programs that allowed one to use php login without mysql.  The slightly modified version (a set of 4) is shown below.  The nice thing about this set is that I use the welcome.php to display a Google Sheet.  Even if one signs in correctly, one cannot easily find where are the user name and password stored, and the name of the Google sheet embedded.

The problem is that this set works on some of the servers but not on others.  Wonder why.  Can somebody help?

I am new at this website and have tried and failed to upload this set programs before.  I am trying it again.

### JTK

### auth.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><!-- InstanceBegin template="/Templates/text.dwt" codeOutsideHTMLIsLocked="false" -->
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Log In</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<h1 align="center" class="style17">Log-in Page</h1>
<br/>
 <h3 align="center" class="red">Please log in
</h3>
<p align="center">
<form method="post" name="auth" action="success.php">
<table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="4" cellpadding="0" align="center">
  <tr>
    <td width="150" align="right">User Name: </td>
    <td><input name="user" type="text" id="user" maxlength="15"></td>
      </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="150" align="right">Password: </td>
    <td><input name="pass" type="password" id="pass" maxlength="20"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="150" align="right">&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
<br>
<?php
if ($flag==wrong)
{
echo "Invalid User Name or Password.  Please try again.";
}
?>
<?php
if ($flag==out)
{
echo "You have logged Out";
}
?>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<hr>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</body>
</html>
```

---

### success.php

```
<?php
session_start();
include("sec.php");
if (($user==USER) && ($pass==PASSWORD))
{
$_SESSION['myuser'] = "ok";
header("Location: welcome.php");
}
else
{
header("Location: auth.php?flag=wrong");
}
?>
```

---

### sec.php

```
<?php
define("USER", "ABC");
define("PASSWORD", "XYZ");
?>
```

---

### welcome.php

```
<?php session_start();
if ($_SESSION['myuser']=="")
{
header("Location: auth.php");
exit;
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Welcome</title>
</head>

<body>
<p align="center">
<h2>You have successfully signed in </h2>
</p>
<p align="center">&nbsp;</p>

<?php session_start();
session_destroy();
$_SESSION = array();
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "does not work" is not really helpful. How exactly this doesn't work? What does the error log say?

Comment: When it works, the URL shows: /welcome.php.  When the server does not work, the URL shows: /auth.php?flag=wrong and the contents in welcome page is not displayed.

Answer (score 1):

The use of, for example, $flag is dependent on how the PHP environment is set up on the server you are using it on (register_globals=true allows such set up while register_globals=false prevents it). Besides, register_globals has been deprecated since PHP 5.4.

I'd suggest that you instead do something like this:

```
if (isset($_GET['flag']) && $_GET['flag'] == "wrong") {
    echo "Invalid User Name or Password.  Please try again.";
}
if (isset($_GET['flag']) && $_GET['flag'] == "out") {
    echo "You have logged Out";
}
```

In that case your GET-parameter checks the flag-variable in a more correct way. And only if it is set.

You should do the same for the variables in success.php, like:

```
if (isset($_POST['user']) && isset($_POST['pass']) && $_POST['user'] == USER && $_POST['pass'] == PASSWORD)
{
    $_SESSION['myuser'] = "ok";
    header("Location: welcome.php");
}
else
{
    header("Location: auth.php?flag=wrong");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I am a novice.  Can you be a little more detail in your answer so I can possibly "copy and replace" sections of my set of programs?  Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks, it now works on servers it did not :-)  

I will study your answer and the comment about register_globals, GET-parameter and the current method.

Found register_gloabals was set to off in v. 4.2.0  So I am lucky it worked on any server at all and my program must be very old.

Anyway, again, thanks, keep up the good work of helping others.